# Angular2-No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: mongodb, http, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to read Json Object from mongodb by doing http call from anhular2 using http provider.

but I am getting the below error in my browser

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3200/pm/workspaces/.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried Below Method i.e. starting chrome by disabling the security restrictions too,but no use:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

below is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class WorkspaceService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }    
    getAllWorkspaces(baseUrl:string) {
         return this.http.get(baseUrl+'/pm/workspaces/')
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
    }
    handleError(error: any) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not related to Angular at all. That needs to be fixed on the server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I m new to node.js.I dont know where to configure server headers.can you provide some pointers?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't know node or Mongodb. I only know that this can't be fixed from the Angular side.